# Dynamic driven open tags preventing posting a tweet

Tags: twitter

We're using open tags in layouts to dynamically drive Twitter and FB previews.

```
{layout:set name="og-tags"}
<meta name="description" content="{intro}" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Remote Learning, Online Learning, Faculty Online Guidance, UMass Boston" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="{banner}{url}{/banner}" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="{title}" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@umbelearning" />
<meta property="og:url" content="{url_title_path}" />
<meta property="og:title" content="{title}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{intro}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{banner}{url}{/banner}" />

{/layout:set}
```

The previews not working on twitter (fine on FB).[image] Page source shows tags rendering image but not displaying.
ex) https://teachonline.umb.edu/course-design,  https://teachonline.umb.edu/assessment etc.  And only homepage even shows the card preview.
[see attached]

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
This syntax is incorrect: `<meta name="twitter:card" content="{banner}{url}{/banner}">`
It should be `<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />`
Used this debugger site -> https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the "/" slash before the ending meta tag.

Check below code.

```
...
<meta name="twitter:card" content="{banner}{url}{/banner}">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="{title}">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@umbelearning">
...
```

Comment: H @zealousWeb I tried that but it doesn't resolve the preview issue,